# Unity3d. Различные анимации для различного оружия

Tags: unity3d

У меня вопрос. Есть набор анимаций для idle, бега, для атаки ближнего и дальнего боя.

Ситуация такова, что они должны отличаться от вида оружия, которое сейчас держит в руках персонаж.

Какой оптимальный способ сделать подобное? Есть ли примеры?

Сейчас это выглядит так - пример набора анимаций для безоружного персонажа. Мне нужно сделать такой набор для каждого вида оружия.

[image: Сейчас это выглядит так]

Comment: У вас 2d или 3d игра?

Comment: самое простое что приходит в голову, это повесить на каждый стейт скрипт, который в рантайме будет менять анимацию этого стейта.

Comment: Игра 3d. А оптимально ли это? Хотелось бы один раз проверить оружие, и в зависимости от выбранного применять тот или иной набор анимаций. Возможно ли использовать слои? Они вроде неплохо выглядят